# Can the word "marker" imply a "turn"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a chapter about Partition of British India. And, in it, there was a section which was titled as:

> A momentous **marker**

I wasn't sure what the word "marker" exactly meant here. And when I checked its translation in the Hindi version of my book, marker was translated to 'मोड़' which means 'turn'. So, what exactly is the meaning of "marker" in this context? Does it mean that "the thing being described as marker" marks a moment in history apart?

Comment: A marker is something that marks. It can mark anything: a turn, the edge of something, the start of something... There is not enough context in your question to be able to help you. Maybe you can add more information.

Comment: *A momentous marker* is far from sufficient to understand what the context for *marker* is. (In a possible context—which I doubt is the case here—If it's a gold-plated ink marker, it might be described as *momentous*.) I suspect that *marker* here means "a point in time," but without real context it's not possible to say with certainty.